# Do I still have to wipe a drive which was encrypted with BitLocker, then formatted?

Tags: windows-10, hard-drive, bitlocker, wipe

I want to sell a HDD. It was BitLocker-encrypted and I formatted it, removing the encryption.

Could there still be recoverable data on the drive? E.g. if I never used all space on the drive while it was encrypted, could there be remnants of unencrypted files from previous uses after the used space?

Comment: If you want to be certain, 0 the hard drive. There are many different software options for how to zero a hard drive.

Comment: "Could there still be recoverable data on the drive?" - **Yes**, Somebody could recover the encrypted data.  Since it's encrypted data they wouldn't be able to do anything with, incomplete data they did recover, since it would be encrypted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to be really, *REALLY* sure the data is unrecoverable, you'll want to run a full overwrite pass (possibly several such overwrites) on the disk. A "full" format does one overwrite, so if you did that, you're probably good. If you did a "quick" format, it only overwrote the volume identification and file system metadata, which might not have even fully deleted the BitLocker metadata (it is stored redundantly in a few locations across the volume); if somebody manages to obtain one of the unlock keys (recovery key, passphrase if you used it without TPM, etc.), they could potentially still recover most of the drive's data at this point (though it would not be trivial).

As a practical matter, though, as long as you don't leak the unlock keys all of your encrypted data is fine. Data that was present and then deleted *before* encryption may or may not have been wiped when BitLocker was set up. There's an option when BL is enabled: encrypt only in-use space, or encrypt free space as well. The latter is intended to handle cases where the drive was in use before getting encrypted and there are deleted or moved file fragments in the "unused" space, so normally if there was anything to be worried about you'd have chosen the full encrypt, but if you didn't (or don't know), running a full wipe is still probably a good idea.